# How can I await inside future-like object's __await__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

[PEP 0492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression) adds new `__await__` magic method. Object that implements this method becomes *future-like object* and can be awaited using `await`. It's clear:

```
import asyncio


class Waiting:
    def __await__(self):
        yield from asyncio.sleep(2)
        print('ok')

async def main():
    await Waiting()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Ok, but what if I want to call some `async def` defined function instead of `asyncio.sleep`? I can't use `await` because `__await__` is not `async` function, I can't use `yield from` because native coroutines requires `await` expression:

```
async def new_sleep():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

class Waiting:
    def __await__(self):
        yield from new_sleep()  # this is TypeError
        await new_sleep()  # this is SyntaxError
        print('ok')
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just implement it as a separate async function inside of the Waiting class? Thus, await Waiting.new_sleep() ?

Comment: @songololo - yes, if you wan't to have your own class of `awaitables`, that's why they provide the `__await__` method. Something will call `await` or e.g. `asyncio.wait_for` on it - and it won't be called from your code.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use direct `__await__()` call:

```
async def new_sleep():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

class Waiting:
    def __await__(self):
        return new_sleep().__await__()
```

The solution was recommended by Yury Selivanov (the author of [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/)) for [aioodbc library](https://github.com/aio-libs/aioodbc/blob/e56615cd005cb402470bbffe6589b38cb5f7acee/aioodbc/utils.py#L27-L28)

Comment: this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46722215/371191 is a little more general, as it allows awaiting multiple awaitables

Answer (score 32):

Short version: `await foo` can be replaced by `yield from foo.__await__()`

---

Combining all the ideas from the other answers -

in the simplest case, just delegating to another awaitable works:

```
def __await__(self):
    return new_sleep().__await__()
```

This works because the `__await__` method returns an iterator (see [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#await-expression)), so returning another `__await__`'s iterator is fine.

This means, of course, that we can't change the suspension behavior of the original awaitable at all. The more general approach is to mirror the `await` keyword and use `yield from` - this lets us combine multiple awaitables' iterators into one:

```
def __await__(self):
    # theoretically possible, but not useful for my example:
    #yield from something_else_first().__await__()
    yield from new_sleep().__await__()
```

Here's the catch: this is not doing exactly the same thing as the first variant! `yield from` is an expression, so to do exactly the same as before, we need to also return that value:

```
def __await__(self):
    return (yield from new_sleep().__await__())
```

This directly mirrors how we would write proper delegation using the `await` syntax:

```
    return await new_sleep()
```

---

extra bit - what's the difference between these two?

```
def __await__(self):
    do_something_synchronously()
    return new_sleep().__await__()

def __await__(self):
    do_something_synchronously()
    return (yield from new_sleep().__await__())
```

The first variant is a plain function: when you call it, `do_...` is executed and an iterator returned. The second is a generator function; calling it doesn't execute any of our code at all! Only when the returned iterator is yielded for the first time will `do_...` be executed. This makes a difference in the following, a little contrived situation:

```
def foo():
    tmp = Waiting.__await__()
    do_something()
    yield from tmp
```

Answer (score 11):

To await inside a `__await__` function, use the following code:

```
async def new_sleep():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)


class Waiting:
    def __await__(self):
        yield from new_sleep().__await__()
        print('first sleep')
        yield from new_sleep().__await__()
        print('second sleep')
        return 'done'
```

Answer (score 8):

I didn't understand why I can't *yield from native coroutine* inside `__await__`, but looks like it's possible to *yield from generator coroutine* inside `__await__` and *yield from native coroutine* inside that *generator coroutine*. It works:

```
async def new_sleep():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

class Waiting:
    def __await__(self):
        @asyncio.coroutine
        def wrapper(coro):
            return (yield from coro)
        return (yield from wrapper(new_sleep()))
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a decorator.

```
def chain__await__(f):
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: f(*args, **kwargs).__await__()
```

Then write `__await__` as a native coroutine.

```
async def new_sleep():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

class Waiting:
    @chain__await__
    async def __await__(self):
        return await new_sleep()
```

Comment: Ideally should have a `functools.wraps` here

Answer (score 4):

Your original code worked fine in Python 3.6.

## Quick Fix (12 characters)

The fixes in other answers are impressive, I couldn't even believe some of them work (but they do!), but I'm afraid if the `asyncio` model keeps being changed, these fixes will stop working.

I have a minimalistic fix, which works on 3.7, without a wrapper:

```
import asyncio


class Waiting:
    def __await__(self):
        yield from asyncio.sleep(2).__await__()
        print('ok')


async def main():
    await Waiting()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The only difference from your original code is adding `.__await__()` to `asyncio.sleep(2)` - even without a wrapper.

## Compatibility approach

You can also us this `sync_await` wrapper around the generator you want to `await` in `__await__`, just like that:

```
import asyncio


def sync_await(gen):
    if hasattr(gen, '__await__'):
        # 3.7, and user defined coroutines in 3.6
        print('yield from gen.__await__()')
        return (yield from gen.__await__())
    else:
        # 3.6, only native coroutines like asyncio.sleep()
        print('yield from gen')
        return (yield from gen)


class Waiting:
    def __await__(self):
        yield from sync_await(asyncio.sleep(2))
        print('ok')


async def main():
    await Waiting()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Note - the wrapper doesn't do `return (yield from ...)`, but `yield from` - simple generator iterator delegation.

Comment: One footnote to this answer - the `sync_await` function is a "generator based coroutine", which Python 3.7 distignuishes from `async def`, the "real" coroutines. The former will be removed in Python 3.10 - so my answer will stop working then; however we'll all have forgotten 3.6 till then (instead of having it almost everywhere).

Comment: I thought only `@asyncio.coroutine` decorator was being removed in 3.10? Won't `@types.coroutine` and everything else remain?

Comment: @Break - wow, I guess you're right. First I thought, that "deprecating GBC" would also mean no coroutines without `async def`, but this could actually still work: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/types.html#types.coroutine (maybe wrapping the function if necessary). I'll check this once I'm using 3.10.