# How can I implement asyncio websockets in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I would like to connect to a websocket via `asyncio` and `websockets`, with a format as shown below. How would I be able to accomplish this?

```
from websockets import connect


class EchoWebsocket:

    def __init__(self):
        self.websocket = self._connect()

    def _connect(self):
        return connect("wss://echo.websocket.org")

    def send(self, message):
        self.websocket.send(message)

    def receive(self):
        return self.websocket.recv()

echo = EchoWebsocket()
echo.send("Hello!")
print(echo.receive())  # "Hello!"
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

How to write async programs?

1. You should define async funcs with `async`
2. You should call async
   funcs with `await`
3. You need [event loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#base-event-loop) to start your async program

All other is almost same as with regular Python programs.

```
import asyncio
from websockets import connect


class EchoWebsocket:
    async def __aenter__(self):
        self._conn = connect("wss://echo.websocket.org")
        self.websocket = await self._conn.__aenter__()        
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        await self._conn.__aexit__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def send(self, message):
        await self.websocket.send(message)

    async def receive(self):
        return await self.websocket.recv()


async def main():
    async with EchoWebsocket() as echo:
        await echo.send("Hello!")
        print(await echo.receive())  # "Hello!"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
Hello!
```

As you see, code is almost same as you wrote.

Only difference is that `websockets.connect` designed to be async context manager (it uses `__aenter__`, `__aexit__`). It's necessary to release connection and will also help you to make async operations during class initialization (since we have no async version of `__init__`).

I advise you to organize your class same way. But if you really don't want to use context manager for some reason you can use new `__await__` method to make async initialization and some other async function to release connection:

```
import sys
import asyncio
from websockets import connect


class EchoWebsocket:
    def __await__(self):
        # see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33420721/1113207
        return self._async_init().__await__()

    async def _async_init(self):
        self._conn = connect("wss://echo.websocket.org")
        self.websocket = await self._conn.__aenter__()
        return self

    async def close(self):
        await self._conn.__aexit__(*sys.exc_info())

    async def send(self, message):
        await self.websocket.send(message)

    async def receive(self):
        return await self.websocket.recv()


async def main():
    echo = await EchoWebsocket()
    try:
        await echo.send("Hello!")
        print(await echo.receive())  # "Hello!"
    finally:
        await echo.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Many examples of using `websockets` you can find in it's [docs](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html).

Comment: this closes after it received a reply. How could it continue receiving messages?

Comment: @FeedTheWeb just keep receiving replies inside context manager.

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov I don't understand the above comment. How do you make sure that the script doesn't end after one reply? Thanks

Comment: @HJA24 if you want to send/receive data constantly, you usually start a server. For example, look at [a code snippet here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#tcp-echo-server-using-streams), specifically line `server.serve_forever()
`. Concrete way to start a server depends on what you want to achieve. Popular high-level library to start servers that works with asyncio is [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html). It provides a way to work with many protocols [including websockets](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#websockets).

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov hi, I am following the docs of a different source where they don't use `server.serve.forever()`, so I am a little bit confused. Can you take a look at my question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61216022/receiving-streaming-data-after-implementing-asyncio-websockets-as-a-class