# How to implement asyncio GET requests as self-contained class?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Much is written about creating self-contained functions for other tasks,

- [How to call a async function contained in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42009202/how-to-call-a-async-function-contained-in-a-class)
- [How to set class attribute with await in __init__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128325/how-to-set-class-attribute-with-await-in-init)

but none address how to do so for GET requests.

Considering the following MWE -- how might this be transformed into a self-contained class?

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

async def get_pokemon(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        pokemon = await resp.json()
        return pokemon['name']

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        tasks = []
        for number in range(1, 151):
            url = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{number}'
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_pokemon(session, url)))

        original_pokemon = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for pokemon in original_pokemon:
            print(pokemon)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Code credit: https://www.twilio.com/blog/asynchronous-http-requests-in-python-with-aiohttp

Comment: What are you having trouble with exactly? Other than turning these functions into `async` methods, what do you need it to do that you're not sure how to do?

Comment: Main() cannot be called from a class.

Comment: Of course it can.  Any function can be called from anywhere as long as its name is in scope.  `class CallMain: async def a_function(self): await main()`