# Passing parameter to a python class when initializing it asynchronously

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37370823/5104314) where they explain how to initialize a class asynchronously with the method `__await__`. The question is: is it possible to pass parameters when awaiting the initialization of the class, just like when it is initialized synchronously?

In other words, I'd like to be able to do
`my_class = await MyClass(my_parameter)`, however I wasn't able to make it work in any way.

Should I just fall back to using the classic `__init__` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33134213/5104314)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use `__init__`. You are creating a regular class instance *first*, and then await on the instance. These are two separate actions.

For example, you could first create the instance, and then later, *separately*, await on it:

```
my_class = MyClass(my_parameter)
result_from_coroutine = await my_class
```

or you could create a task from it and have the event loop execute it with

```
my_class = MyClass(my_parameter)
task = asyncio.create_task(my_class)  # the loop will await the task
# ...
if task.done():
    result_from_coroutine = task.result()
```

The `__await__` method is what `await` or the event loop use to drive coroutines. The same separation applies to coroutine functions (defined with `async def`); they too create a new coroutine object when you call them, and you don't have to await on them immediately. You can use `await` on the result at another time.

If you are looking for asynchronous *instance creation*, then you could hack that up by making the [`__new__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) into a coroutine:

```
>>> class Async:
...     async def __new__(cls):
...         instance = super().__new__(cls)
...         return instance
...
>>> Async()
<coroutine object Async.__new__ at 0x103654148>
```

Awaiting on the coroutine would create the actual instance and return it.

Take into account that this does mean that the `__init__` method *will* be skipped; the latter is only called when the `__new__` method directly returns an instance of the class (or a subclass), and a coroutine is not such an instance. You'd have to explicitly do so yourself:

```
class Async:
    async def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return instance
```

at which point you could decide to make the `__init__` method a coroutine too.

Note that this is *really* going against the grain. I'd postpone calling dependent coroutines to a later point instead.

For example, you can just store the parameters to the class on the instance and use those when the instance is awaited on (by having `__await__` called), exactly as the post you link to advices you to do.

Comment: The reason why I'm doing an asynchronous initialization is because I'm awaiting a few methods that need to be run as soon as the class is created, but because they are private methods I didn't want to call them "outside" of the class itself.

Comment: @FedericoCorazza: you can't create instances asynchronously.

Comment: @FedericoCorazza: that's because the process of creating instances isn't handled by `__init__`, that's just a hook called *after* the instance is already created.

Comment: This is very interesting, but I agree, I should call the awaitables later on.

Answer (score 0):

> In other words, I'd like to be able to do `my_class = await MyClass(my_parameter)`, however I wasn't able to make it work in any way.

You can make `MyClass` awaitable by implementing `__await__`:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, delay):
        self.delay = delay

    async def __await__(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(self.delay)

asyncio.run(MyClass(2)) # sleeps 2 seconds
```

The code in the linked answer does a similar thing, but it is more complex because it assumes that `__init__` itself requires `await`. If that is not the case, and your `__init__` is in fact trivial, but you want the returned instance to be awaitable, you don't need the added complexity of a split initialization.

Note: despite being [recommended](https://speakerdeck.com/1st1/asyncio-today-and-tomorrow?slide=14), `asyncio.run()` is still marked provisional. In the above example it can be easily replaced with `run_until_complete`.

Comment: I'll play with this a little bit. Thank you

Comment: @FedericoCorazza Sorry about the rejected edit, I didn't know that it was done by the same person who asked the question. I've now amended the answer to mention the provisional status of `asyncio.run`.