# Receiving streaming data after implementing asyncio websockets as a class?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

My question is closely related to the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42009202/how-to-call-a-async-function-contained-in-a-class) on Stackoverflow and the documentation [here](https://docs.deribit.com/#deribit_price_index-index_name).
I am defining a `websockets`-connection as a class. Next, I create a new class where I call the earlier defined websocket-class as `self.ws` and tell which data to send to the websocket with `self.request`.
My problem is that the current script only runs once, whereas my desired output is continuous data.

The second link shows that I can retrieve continuous / streaming data using

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(call_api(json.dumps(msg)))
```

I include all of the above code in my code (`call_api` is defined differently due to the desire to write it as a class). Below is my code:

```
import sys, json
import asyncio
from websockets import connect

class EchoWebsocket:
   def __init__(self, URL, CLIENT_ID=None, CLIENT_SECRET=None):
      self.url = URL
      self.client_id = CLIENT_ID
      self.client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET

   async def __aenter__(self):
      self._conn = connect(self.url)
      self.websocket = await self._conn.__aenter__()
      return self

   async def __aexit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      await self._conn.__aexit__(*args, **kwargs)

   async def send(self, message):
      await self.websocket.send(message)

   async def receive(self):
      return await self.websocket.recv()

class DERIBIT:
   def __init__(self):
      self.ws = EchoWebsocket(URL='wss://test.deribit.com/ws/api/v2')
      self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
      self.request = \
                   {"jsonrpc": "2.0",
                    "method": "public/subscribe",
                    "id": 42,
                    "params": {
                        "channels": ["deribit_price_index.btc_usd"]}
                   }

   def get_ticks(self):
      return self.loop.run_until_complete(self.__async__get_ticks())

   async def __async__get_ticks(self):
      async with self.ws as echo:
         await echo.send(json.dumps(self.request))
         response = await echo.receive()
         print(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   deribit = DERIBIT()
   deribit.get_ticks()
```

This script gives the following output:

> {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "public/subscribe", "id": 42, "params": {"channels": ["deribit_price_index.btc_usd"]}}

whereas I would like to see

[image]

Please advice.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `while True` around the whole `async with` block in `__async__get_ticks`? You could also add a loop around `run_until_complete` in `get_ticks`, which is what the linked answer does, but adding the while in the async function is better style because it enables you to use `asyncio.run` and completely rid of the sync `get_ticks` method.

Comment: hi, I tried that by placing `while True` after `async with self.ws as echo`, but I am getting the following error:     raise self.connection_closed_exc()
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedOK: code = 1000 (OK), reason = over_limit

Comment: Did you get the desired output before the error?

Comment: yes, it works before the connection gets closed. I think each time I print the output the connection closes and gets reconnected again, resulting in an overload. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

I only worked with Tornado's websockets but they work pretty well and Tornado has many helpers for dealing with *async* code:

```py
import json
import tornado
from tornado.ioloop import PeriodicCallback
from tornado.websocket import websocket_connect


class EchoWebsocket:

    def __init__(self, url, client_id=None, client_secret=None):
        self.url = url
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.client_secret = client_secret
        self.websocket = None

    async def connect(self):
        if not self.websocket:
            self.websocket = await websocket_connect(self.url)

    async def close(self):
        await self.websocket.close()
        self.websocket = None

    async def read(self):
        return await self.websocket.read_message()

    async def write(self, message):
        await self.websocket.write_message(message)


class DERIBIT:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ws = EchoWebsocket(url='wss://test.deribit.com/ws/api/v2')
        self.request = {
            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
            "method": "public/subscribe",
            "id": 42,
            "params": {
                "channels": ["deribit_price_index.btc_usd"]}
        }
        self.callback = PeriodicCallback(self.get_ticks, 1000)
        self.callback.start()

    async def get_ticks(self):
        if not self.ws.websocket:
            await self.ws.connect()
        await self.ws.write(json.dumps(self.request))
        response = await self.ws.read()
        print(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    deribit = DERIBIT()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Output:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":42,"result":["deribit_price_index.btc_usd"],"usIn":1587298852138977,"usOut":1587298852139023,"usDiff":46,"testnet":true}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"subscription","params":{"channel":"deribit_price_index.btc_usd","data":{"timestamp":1587298851526,"price":7173.46,"index_name":"btc_usd"}}}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"subscription","params":{"channel":"deribit_price_index.btc_usd","data":{"timestamp":1587298852533,"price":7173.53,"index_name":"btc_usd"}}}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":42,"result":["deribit_price_index.btc_usd"],"usIn":1587298852932540,"usOut":1587298852932580,"usDiff":40,"testnet":true}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"subscription","params":{"channel":"deribit_price_index.btc_usd","data":{"timestamp":1587298852533,"price":7173.53,"index_name":"btc_usd"}}}
```

The example above could be simplified a lot if you integrate the websocket into the DERIBIT class rather than create a separate class for it.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in the function

first `loop.run_until_complete`  run until the future is complete [doc run_until_complete](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_until_complete)
that mean your function receive will run only one response.    `run_until_complete` is not a `callback` function!.

so in your case the `main`:
 `deribit.get_ticks()`  -> run the future instance `__async__get_ticks`
 so `__async__get_ticks` is task: let's see what the task do:
    1.open ws connection:
    2.send request
    3.wait the response of the ws
    4. print(response)
    `here the task is done` that why you see only one line

```
   async def __async__get_ticks(self):
      async with self.ws as echo:
         await echo.send(json.dumps(self.request))
         response = await echo.receive()
         print(response)
```

after explanation: the solution will be simple: 
need to wrap the line `response`
 with while

```
async def __async__get_ticks(self):
      async with self.ws as echo:
         await echo.send(json.dumps(self.request))
         while True:
                response = await echo.receive()
                print(response)
```

output

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"subscription","params":{"channel":"deribit_price_index.btc_usd","data":{"timestamp":1587654476817,"price":7540.54,"index_name":"btc_usd"}}}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"subscription","params":{"channel":"deribit_price_index.btc_usd","data":{"timestamp":1587654477824,"price":7540.52,"index_name":"btc_usd"}}}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"subscription","params":{"channel":"deribit_price_index.btc_usd","data":{"timestamp":1587654478831,"price":7540.15,"index_name":"btc_usd"}}}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"subscription","params":{"channel":"deribit_price_index.btc_usd","data":{"timestamp":1587654479838,"price":7539.83,"index_name":"btc_usd"}}}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"subscription","params":{"channel":"deribit_price_index.btc_usd","data":{"timestamp":1587654480845,"price":7539.2,"index_name":"btc_usd"}}}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"subscription","params":{"channel":"deribit_price_index.btc_usd","data":{"timestamp":1587654481852,"price":7538.96,"index_name":"btc_usd"}}}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"subscription","params":{"channel":"deribit_price_index.btc_usd","data":{"timestamp":1587654482859,"price":7538.9,"index_name":"btc_usd"}}}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"subscription","params":{"channel":"deribit_price_index.btc_usd","data":{"timestamp":1587654483866,"price":7538.89,"index_name":"btc_usd"}}}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"subscription","params":{"channel":"deribit_price_index.btc_usd","data":{"timestamp":1587654484873,"price":7538.47,"index_name":"btc_usd"}}}
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"subscription","params":{"channel":"deribit_price_index.btc_usd","data":{"timestamp":1587654485880,"price":7537.15,"index_name":"btc_usd"}}}
```