# How to wait 5 seconds (without blocking) before sending Response?

Tags: python-asyncio, sanic

This seems to be possible because in `app.Sanic.handle_request()` there's this [snippet](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic/blob/master/sanic/app.py#L564):

```
            if isawaitable(response):
                response = await response
```

And this is how `awaitable` is checked by Python:

```
def isawaitable(object):
    """Return true if object can be passed to an ``await`` expression."""
    return (isinstance(object, types.CoroutineType) or
            isinstance(object, types.GeneratorType) and
                bool(object.gi_code.co_flags & CO_ITERABLE_COROUTINE) or
            isinstance(object, collections.abc.Awaitable))
```

I know to use `async def` to create an awaitable function, but I don't know how to create an awaitable [`HTTPResponse`](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic/blob/master/sanic/response.py#L175) instance. It would really help to see an example of an awaitable response with a simple `await asyncio.sleep(5)` if possible.

---

Tried the solution by Mikhail, here's what I observed:

- `raise500` enters the `asyncio.sleep()`
- `ret500` does not enter the `asyncio.sleep()` (bug)
- `raise500` blocks other `raise500` (bug)
- `raise500` does not block `ret500`
- Cannot tell if `ret500` would block other `ret500` because it's too fast (not sleeping)

Full code (run by saving as `test.py`, then in shell `python test.py` and going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test`):

```
import asyncio
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import HTTPResponse
from sanic.handlers import ErrorHandler


class AsyncHTTPResponse(HTTPResponse):  # make it awaitable
    def __await__(self):
        return self._coro().__await__()  # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33420721/1113207

    async def _coro(self):
        print('Sleeping')
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print('Slept 5 seconds')
        return self


class CustomErrorHandler(ErrorHandler):
    def response(self, request, exception):
        return AsyncHTTPResponse(status=500)


app = Sanic(__name__, error_handler=CustomErrorHandler())


@app.get("/api/test")
async def test(request):
    return HTTPResponse(status=204)


@app.get("/api/raise500")
async def raise500(request):
    raise Exception


@app.get("/api/ret500")
async def ret500(request):
    return AsyncHTTPResponse(status=500)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class that implements `__await__` magic method becomes awaitable.

I didn't check if it'll work in your case, but here is example of creating awaitable custom class instance:

```
import asyncio
from inspect import isawaitable


class HTTPResponse:  # class we have
    pass


class AsyncHTTPResponse(HTTPResponse):  # make it awaitable
    def __await__(self):
        return self._coro().__await__()  # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33420721/1113207

    async def _coro(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        return self


async def main():
    resp = AsyncHTTPResponse()

    if isinstance(resp, HTTPResponse):
        print('It is HTTPResponse class ...')

    if isawaitable(resp):
        print('... which is also awaitable.')

    print('Let us see how it works.')
    await resp


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
    loop.close()
```

Comment: It partially works under some conditions, I edited the OP with my observations

Answer (score 3):

Since Mikhail's answer is the right one, I will only discuss the further edit

> - raise500 blocks other raise500 (bug)

It does not seem to block. A simple test (added some query string to distinguish requests):

```
for i in `seq 2`;do curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/raise500&req=$i & done
```

From the log's datetime it looks that there is not delay (block) between requests

```
Sleeping
Sleeping
Slept 5 seconds
2017-11-26 01:01:49 - (network)[INFO][127.0.0.1:37310]: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/raise500?req=1  500 0
Slept 5 seconds
2017-11-26 01:01:49 - (network)[INFO][127.0.0.1:37308]: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/raise500?req=2  500 0
```

> - ret500 does not enter the asyncio.sleep() (bug)

It's because you return awaitable in awaitable function, but sanic await only for the first one:

```
@app.get("/api/ret500")
async def ret500(request):
    return AsyncHTTPResponse(status=500)
```

The `handle_request` does:

```
response = ret500(request)  # call `async def ret500` and returns awaitable
if isawaitable(response):
    response = await response  # resolve and returns another awaitable - AsyncHTTPResponse object

# note to wait 5 seconds sanic would need again await for it
# response = await response
```

Solutions:

1. do not return awaitable, in other words `await AsyncHTTPResponse` by yourself

   ```
   @app.get("/api/ret500")
   async def ret500(request):
       res = await AsyncHTTPResponse(status=500)
       return res
   ```
2. drop ret500's `async`

   ```
   @app.get("/api/ret500")
   def ret500(request):
       return AsyncHTTPResponse(status=500)
   ```

   Note: this technique is only valid if do not intend to call async functions in it.