# Test if coroutine was awaited or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-3.7

I have an asynchronous function which connects to a database. Currently 
my users do:

```
conn = await connect(uri, other_params)
```

I want to continue to support this, but want to additionally allow `connect()` to be used as a context manager:

```
async with connect(uri, other_params) as conn:
     pass
```

The difference between these two scenarios is that in the first case `connect` is awaited, and in the second case it is not.

Is it possible to tell, *within the body of `connect`*, if the coroutine was awaited or not?

My current effort at this on [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/DefensiveCompleteConfig).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's code that passes tests you provided:

```
import asyncio
import pytest
from functools import wraps


def connection_context_manager(func):
  @wraps(func)
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

    class Wrapper:
        def __init__(self):
          self._conn = None

        async def __aenter__(self):
            self._conn = await func(*args, **kwargs)
            return self._conn

        async def __aexit__(self, *_):
          await self._conn.close()

        def __await__(self):
            return func(*args, **kwargs).__await__()  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/33420721/1113207
    return Wrapper()

  return wrapper
```

Note how three magic methods allows us to make object awaitable and async context manager at the same time.

Feel free to ask questions if you have any.

Comment: Great answer! I'd just recommend avoiding creating a new class every time the decorator is invoked because classes are comparatively heavyweight and slow to construct. And it's quite easy to avoid it - just define `Wrapper` at top-level, pass `func` to its constructor, and use `self._func` where needed.

Comment: You and @user4815162342 are my heroes. This is good stuff. I actually didn't know there was an `__await__` magic. Thanks both.

Comment: @user4815162342's answer is shown in detail [on my Github](https://github.com/roblevy/async-and-sync)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a structural issue in your example.

So first your example needs to `await` the `__call__`:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_connect_with_context_manager():
    async with await connect("with context uri") as no_context:
        # Now it's open
        assert no_context.open

    # Now it's closed
    assert not no_context.open
```

But here the problem is, the result of `await connect("with context uri")` is a `Connection`, which doesn't even have `__aexit__` method.

So I believe you should change the structure totally, adding `connect` method to the `Connection` to actually make a connection, and in `MagicConnection`, delegating every method of the `Connection`.