# How can I apply Locks in Python on a non-asynchronous function?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm trying to create an implementation to be able to apply lru_cache to Python coroutines, so I have the following:

```
from asyncio import Lock, sleep
class ThreadSafeCacheable:
    def __init__(self, coro_func):
        self.coro_func = coro_func
        self.done = False
        self.result = None
        self.lock = Lock()

    def __await__(self):
        while True:
            if self.done:
                return self.result
            if not self.lock.locked():
                try:
                    self.lock.acquire()
                    self.result = yield from self.coro_func().__await__()
                    self.done = True
                finally:
                    self.lock.release()
                return self.result
            else:
                yield from sleep(0.005)

def cacheable(coro_func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return ThreadSafeCacheable(lambda: coro_func(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapper

@lru_cache(maxsize=8)
    @cacheable
    async def get_company_id(self, simulation_id: int):
        simulation_in_db = await self.get_by_id(_id=simulation_id)
        if not simulation_in_db:
            raise ValueError("Simulation not found")
        company_id = simulation_in_db["company_id"]
        return company_id
```

The idea is that it is safe to use between coroutines, therefore I thought about implementing asyncio Locks, as shown in the code. But, logically I get:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Lock.acquire' was never awaited
```

However, I cannot async the **await** function.
What option do I have to implement it?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409888/how-can-i-await-inside-future-like-objects-await/46722215#46722215